# Filter other than this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

How to filter the current item from the list of items. Eg.

```
$('.div').click(
    function (){
        $(this).val('this is clicked');

        //! get the items that are not clicked

    }
)
```

`$('.div')` returns a list of items, and one of them is clicked. How to get the list of item, that are not clicked.

**Note:** I am not looking the solution that adds attribute to the clicked item (or unlicked item) and filters it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('.div').click(
    function (){

        $(this).val('this is clicked');

        var others = $(".div").not($(this));

    }
)
```

Comment: exactly does what i indent to do

Answer (score 2):

Try the [siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).siblings()
```

Comment: I thought about that but it assumes no other elements at the same level in the tree.

Comment: Is it possible that elements he's trying to select are not siblings, they could be anywhere in the DOM. Perhaps the question asker could clarify.

Comment: it helpful but my classes are not in same level i.e. they are in different wrapper anyway it was informative

Answer (score 0):

How about `$('.div:not(this)')`?